# No initial activity found for subprocess"

Tags: activiti, bpmn

"No initial activity found for subprocess", what is the root cause of this error?

org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: No initial activity found for subprocess subprocess2

From source code, understood that this exception is thrown when there is no parameter named "initail" is attached in the xml bpm parser. But not able to find any documentation regarding this "initial" parameter any where in bpm/activiti-bpm. Please share some information if available.

This occurs in my event based subprocess where i have used a mail start event to start the subprocess.

I seriously doubt if this is a bug in activiti. Please find my findings below:
1. I have modelled my bpd with multiple subprocesses.
2. started each sub process with message start events.
Then I got exception and going through doc I understood that subprocess supports only none start event as start of the flow.
3. So I edited all my subprocess containers and added following attribute :
**triggeredByEvent="true"** so that they are now become event subprocess with message start event as start events.But when I ran it I got exception saying **"No initial activity found for subprocess"**.
4. Now I resolved the issue by a work around. Changed all event subprocesses into normal subprocess. Added none start event followed by an intermediate message catch event.

Initial bpd giving error:
[image]
Current bpd without error:
[image]

Please check if this is a valid issue.

Comment: please share your bmp.xml

Answer (score 3):

A sub process needs a start event. This exception makes me think you don't have a start event defined in your sub process activity.